# What type of art is this?

Tags: style-identification, games

I wanted to know what the name was of this type of images? I am basically asking for the name of the style that these were done in?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The second is a screenshot from the upcoming proceedurally generated indie video game called "No Man's Sky".

Comment: @Neuroavalanche This has nothing to do with the style of the image.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see one particular aesthetic to either of those.

In terms of what 'type' of artwork that is, a number of descriptors could apply:

- concept art (typically for movies/games)
- matte paintings/background artwork
- landscapes

Comment: I also don't see a style, i do see good use of contrast: contrasting colors, contrasting detail vs basic shapes,  contrasting dark and light, and even contrasting environments with objects / characters.

Comment: agree with @Daniel, that I don't see any style

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the first one is a combination of concept art (as @DA01 mentioned) with fantasy artwork, or possibly futuristic painting artwork.

The second one, I have no idea! Possibly indie futuristing paintwork.